# Randomize sound in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity

When I start my game, public AudioSource does not load sound but play a sound.  My code does not have any error.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class random: MonoBehaviour {

    public AudioClip[] gravel;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!GetComponent<AudioSource>().isPlaying){
            GetComponent<AudioSource>().PlayOneShot(gravel[Random.Range(0,gravel.Length-1)]);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I put my random audio to my audio source.
[Video for describle my problem:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-1NrBmZJDU2d05WTlZWOHFVSE0/view)
In this video play sound twice (because I run my game twice)
In first play I have to attach a file to audio source.
I do not know why my audio source is empty and I have to attach a file to it.
If I can load sound in my audio source I can fix my problem.
I want to play one randomized shot.

Comment: What do you mean by first play and second play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your first sound playing well because you assigned it explicitly and you have mark on check **Play On Awake**.Uncheck it.

You can do something like,

```
public AudioClip[] _gravel;
private AudioSource _aSource;

void Start()
{
    // Get attach audio source once.
    _aSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();

    // Start Coroutine for playing sounds. Call it once
    StartCoroutine("PlaySound");
}

void Update()
{
}

IEnumerator PlaySound()
{
    _aSource.clip = _gravel[Random.Range(0,_gravel.Length)];
    _aSource.Play();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(_aSource.clip.length);
    StartCoroutine("PlaySound");

}

// ===== OR ===== //

IEnumerator PlaySound()
{
    while(true){
        _aSource.clip = _gravel[Random.Range(0,_gravel.Length)];
        _aSource.Play();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(_aSource.clip.length);   
    } 
}
```